# Sorting alphanumeric data based on leading digits in PivotTables

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a data set that goes something like this:

```
10 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************   
11 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************     
11 kVA - *****************   
11 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************   
12 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************     
12 kVA - *****************  
2.4 kVA - *****************    
2.4 kVA - *****************   
2.4 kVA - *****************   
2.4 kVA - *****************   
2.4 kVA - *****************    
2.4 kVA - *****************    
2.4 kVA - *****************    
2.4 kVA - *****************    
2.4 kVA - ****************         
3 kVA - ***************
```

where `*****************` indicate alphanumeric string.

Now as evident from above, sorting is totally messed up. Can anyone please tell me how to sort this data based on `xx kVA` in a PivotTable? Specifically:

```
2.4 kVA  
.  
.  
.  
3 kVA    
.  
.  
.  
4 kVA  
.  
.  
.  
9 kVA  
.  
.  
.  
10 kVA  
.  
.  
.  
12 kVA
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is your data contained within one column only?

Comment: Yes, all the entries are contained in one column of the Pivot Table.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I would suggest getting one additional column in the source table where the number before `kVA` will be generated, and then include this column in the row labels part of the pivot table for sorting purposes. If you are okay, I can elaborate more on how to do this exactly.

Comment: Okay I have deleted the Pivot Table and pasted the column as values. Can you help me sort them now? Thanks!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zecs9.png
This is how the data looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to sort them now that you have pasted the data as values, you need to insert a new column. Let's assume that the data is currently in column B. Insert a column before it, so that the new column is column B and the data is in column C.

[I'm assuming that you have headers].

Put the formula:

```
=LEFT(C2, FIND(" ",C2)-1)*1
```

in cell B2 and drag the formula down to the bottom, put a filter and you can sort by column B, which will automatically sort column C as well. I hope is what you were looking for!

EDIT: You can do the same thing from the source data and you get something like:

[image]

Notice that the first PivotTable isn't properly sorted since I don't have the `ID` column. Note also that the `ID` column has the formula I mentioned, adapted for the current cell `A2`. When I do a pivot with the ID, I get the data properly sorted, which you can also hide so that you don't see the `#VALUE!` part.

Comment: No but I have this data in blocks; I need to sort only within that block. I can't sort the entire column since it contains other entries as well.

Comment: Please check this image to get a better understanding of the data set: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A0ysY.png

Comment: @MuneebM Then I would suggest inserting this formula in a new column in the source data of your pivot table (the sheet on which you based your pivot table on, the method I talked about in an earlier comment). Once you extracted this data, you can run a pivot. See my edited answer.

Comment: Looks like I can sort the block by selecting both column B (helper column) and column C (data column) and then using Custom Sort (Smallest to Largest) on column B. But I have like around 100 similar blocks; is there anyway to do this quickly? Thanks!

Comment: @MuneebM Did you try adding the helper column before creating the PivotTable as in my edited answer?

Comment: No, I'm doing that right now.

Comment: @MuneebM Okay, let me know what you get! :)

Comment: Man I need some more help please. So basically I'm trying to create dynamic named ranges to be used in conjunction with Data validation. Specifically, I'm looking to use the same data set (Pivot Tables or pasted values) to display different range of products based on user input. For example, I need 10 cells to display a list of _AT1_SPC_ALL products (10 kVA - asdf) and another 10 to display _AT1_SPC products (Antenna etc). On a higher level, I need this replicated for 10 blocks. So it would be 4 categories within each block and 10 blocks in total. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @MuneebM I suggest you create another question and link to this one, since it's a different problem pertaining to the same dataset, and I don't think I'm following you well. I would ask for a screenshot of what you want to achieve. You can use dummy values, like how I did in the picture of my answer!

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795784/automatically-updating-data-validation-lists-based-on-user-input