# Automatically updating Data Validation lists based on user input

Tags: excel-2010, validation

I have a very large data set (about 16k rows). I have 10 higher level blocks and within each block I have 4 categories (10 rows for each) which use Data Validation lists to show items available in each category. The lists should automatically update based on user input. What I need your help with is that I want to use the same data set for each block and preferably a least calculation/size intensive approach. I have put together a sample file that outlines the issue with examples.

[Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chktfq1rfajttcv/Sample_File.xlsx)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm looking into it, but it seems awfully complicated. I managed to make the output contain only `_FIN` where the user picks it, and only `_GER` where the user picks it, but I can't seem to go further with `CNY` and `CNY2`. And that said, only one such block will work at a time from that method I'm using. Maybe VBA could do it, but I'm not good at it yet :( Will let you know if I find something!

Comment: Actually the user only has to pick `_FIN` or `_GER`; `_CNY` and `_CNY2` will always be fixed for each category. For example, the first category will ALWAYS be `_CNY` and second category will always be `_CNY2` in each block. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, that's where I'm stuck actually! When the user picks `_FIN`, all the `_FIN` appear, as opposed to one part `_CNY` and the other `_CNY2`. And the other problem is that there're a lot of blanks in the dropdown. For instance, [this is as far as I got](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Sample_File.xlsx).

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for working on it. But there are two issues with this approach:
1. Empty entries in the drop downs
2. I can't afford to drag that `VLOOKUP` down to 16k rows. It will increase the size of the file substantially.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found something, but it can be quite time consuming to do.

1. Select each range of cells. For instance, for the first one, select `B3:B18` and right click on the selection. Find 'Name a Range..." and give it the name "_FIN_CNY". Repeat for all the other ranges, changing the name where necessary.
2. Select the first range of cells to get the data validation, and click on "Data validation", pick the option "Allow: List" (you already have it) and then in the source, put the formula:

   ```
   =INDIRECT($G$4&"_CNY")
   ```

   `$G$4` is where the user will input. This changes as you change blocks.
   `_CNY` is the category. Change it to `_CNY2` for the second category.
3. Click "OK" and this should be it. Repeat for the other categories.

I have put an [updated file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Sample_File2.xlsx) on dropbox where you can see I already did it for the data of `_FIN` for categories `CNY`, `CNY2` and `INT` and did the one for `_GER` as well. You'll notice the category of `INT` for `_GER` doesn't work, that's because the Named Range `_GER_INT` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I will have to create around 1500 named ranges if I use this approach.

Comment: @MuneebM You will probably be better off with MS Access with that =/ Using forms and queries together should yield a better system.

Comment: Can't use MS Access. It has to be Excel only, and offline.